# Property is missing in type but required in a different type?

Tags: typescript

Still trying to wrap my head around typescript.

I'm trying to type a destructured object like so:

`const { authError }: {authError: string}  = useRouterQuery()`

authError must be a string to work well with other components, but `useRouterQuery()` is using a different type: `ParsedUrlQuery`.

So I'm getting the following typescript error: `Property 'authError' is missing in type 'ParsedUrlQuery' but required in type '{ authError: string; }'.`

Hoping someone can explain the cleanest solution for this.

EDIT: `ParsedUrlQuery` type returns:

```
type ParsedUrlQuery = {
    [x: string]: string | string[] | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Is that not telling you the right thing? You can't destructure authError from the return value because it doesn't have that property. Or maybe the type is wrong, but without a [mre] we can't tell.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited my question with what ParsedUrlQuery returns, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing You can do - it is typeguard:

```js
type ParsedUrlQuery = {
    [x: string]: string | string[] | undefined;
}

/**
 * Just a mock
 */
const useRouterQuery = () => ({}) as ParsedUrlQuery

const isAuthorError = (arg: any): arg is { authError: NonNullable<ParsedUrlQuery[string]> } => typeof arg?.authError === 'string'

const result = useRouterQuery()

if (isAuthorError(result)) {
    /**
     * Now you can be sure that authError is either string or string[]
     */
    const { authError } = result
}


const { authError }: ParsedUrlQuery = useRouterQuery()
```

There is no other way that TS compiler will figure out if `authError` exists or not.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) you can find more about typeguards

Answer (score 0):

From the example above, looks like `ParsedUrlQuery` is an object that has keys of type string (`[x: string]`) and values which can be `string`, `string[]`, or `undefined`.

Like the error mentions, that type doesn't explicitly include an `authError` key.

What you can do is `const { authError }: ParsedUrlQuery = useRouterQuery()`

This way, if the object that useRouterQuery returns has an `authError` key, it'll be destructured and of type `string | string[] | undefined`.